# How to determine the class of a descriptor?

Tags: python

In this example code, I would like to determine if `x` is an instance of `TestProperty`:

```
class TestProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        return getattr(instance, self._name)

    def __set_(self, instance, value):
        setattr(instance, self._name, value)

class Test(object):
    x = TestProperty("x")

print isinstance(Test.x, TestProperty)
```

However, I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zenoss/testproperties.py", line 14, in <module>
    print isinstance(Test.x, TestProperty)
  File "/home/zenoss/testproperties.py", line 6, in __get__
    return getattr(instance, self._name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Is there anyway to tell if an attribute is an instance of a class when it is a descriptor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the current `__get__`, `Test.x` causes the `AttributeError` because when the code accessing the descriptor using class, `instance` is passed `None`; (=> `getattr(None, 'x')` => `None.x`)

You should modify `__get__` to handle such case:

```
>>> class TestProperty(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self._name = name
...     def __get__(self, instance, cls):
...         if instance is None:  # To handle access through class, not instance
...             return self       # returns the TestProperty instance itself.
...         return getattr(instance, self._name)
...     def __set_(self, instance, value):
...         setattr(instance, self._name, value)
... 
>>> class Test(object):
...     x = TestProperty("x")
... 
>>> isinstance(Test.x, TestProperty)
True
```

---

BTW, as you may know, with `x = TestProperty("x")`, accessing `x` attribute through an instance will cause another exception, because it will call the `__get__` (-> getattr(..) -> __get__ -> getattr(..) -> ...) recursively until stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks, returning `self` when `instance is None` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement a property is with the `@property` decorator:

```
class TestProperty(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        """Getter for '_name'."""
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        """Setter for '_name'."""
        self._name = value

class Test(object):
    x = TestProperty("x")

print(isinstance(Test.x, TestProperty))
```

It returns `True` when I run it.
See the documentation for `@property` at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property.